# get updated date field row after inner joining table

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where a row is inserted whenever a schedule is created with call_back_date value
`la_id` is the same for each row, i want get a most recent row that is `max(call_back_date)`
I have written this query which fetch all the entries for those schedule after inner joining three tables:

```
SELECT
la_details.application_no, 
la_details.id la_det,
la_details.client_id client_id,
la_details.la_name la_name,
la_details.sex sex,
la_details.advisor_name advisor_name,
la_details.client_phone client_phone,
la_details.client_mobile client_mibile,
la_details.level level,
la_details.state state,
la_details.pin_code pin_code,
trans_schedules.id schedule_id, 
trans_schedules.*, 
comments.descriptions
FROM
la_details
INNER JOIN trans_schedules 
ON 
trans_schedules.la_id=la_details.id
INNER JOIN comments  
ON 
comments.comment_id=trans_schedules.comment_id
WHERE
(trans_schedules.comment_id<>'1' 
OR
trans_schedules.list_followup = '1'
OR
trans_schedules.counter_flag='0') 
AND 
la_details.case_closed='0'
ORDER BY 
trans_schedules.call_back_date 
) a1 INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT la_id,MAX(call_back_date) AS call_back_date from
trans_schedules group by la_id                                                               
) b1 on a1.la_det = b1.la_id and a1.call_back_date  = b1.call_back_date
```

My question is how could i use a subquery on previous query to get max call_back_date row
Thanks in advance for help!!!!

Comment: How about SCOPE_IDENTITY()??

Comment: I'm not used to with scope_identity of mysql. Can you please elaborate or any other possibility.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

Select LAST_INSERT_ID();

It will give you last inserted identity record